# Remotely check status of cassandra using nodetool. Error: Connection refused

Tags: docker, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, janusgraph

I am trying create a docker compose setup which will wait until the Cassandra container has started before running the JanusGraph container which requires Cassandra to be running before starting.

The nodetool command seems to be the standard way to check the status of Cassandra. Here is what I get running nodetool first on the cassandra container:

```
docker exec -it ns-orchestration_data_storage_1 nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.31.0.2  235.53 KiB  256          100.0%            eea17329-6274-45a7-a9fb-a749588b733a  rack1
```

The first "UN" on the last stdout line means Up/Normal which I intend to use in my wait-for-cassandra-and-elasticsearch.sh script. But now when I try to run it on the janusgraph container (remote) I am getting this:

```
docker exec -it ns-orchestration_data_janusgraph_1 bin/nodetool -h 172.31.0.2 -u cassandra -pw <my-password-here> status
docker exec -it ns-orchestration_data_janusgraph_1 bin/nodetool -h 
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/app/janusgraph-0.3.0-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/app/janusgraph-0.3.0-hadoop2/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
nodetool: Failed to connect to '172.31.0.2:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

I have exposed all Cassandra ports as you can see in the docker-compose file below.

I also saw [this post](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureJmxAuthentication.html) which I am not sure is related. I tried following the instructions but I am still getting the same error.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

File: docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  data_janusgraph:
    build:
      context: ../ns-compute-store/db-janusgraph
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.janusgraph
    ports:
      - "8182:8182"
    depends_on:
      - data_storage
      - data_index
    networks:
      - ns-net
  data_storage:
    build:
      context: ../ns-compute-store/db-janusgraph
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.cassandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true
    ports:
      - "9160:9160"
      - "9042:9042"
      - "7199:7199"
      - "7001:7001"
      - "7000:7000"
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/cassandra
    networks:
      - ns-net
  data_index:
    image: elasticsearch:5.6
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - ns-net
networks:
  ns-net:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  data-volume:
```

File: Dockerfile.cassandra

```
FROM cassandra:3.11
COPY conf/jmxremote.password /etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password
RUN chown cassandra:cassandra /etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password
RUN chmod 400 /etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password
COPY conf/jmxremote.access /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.access
RUN chown cassandra:cassandra /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.access
RUN chmod 400 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.access
COPY conf/cassandra.yaml /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

File: Dockerfile.janusgraph

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk --no-cache add unzip
RUN wget https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/download/v0.3.0/janusgraph-0.3.0-hadoop2.zip
RUN unzip janusgraph-0.3.0-hadoop2.zip
RUN apk --no-cache add bash coreutils nmap
RUN apk del unzip
ENV JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=data_storage"
WORKDIR /app/janusgraph-0.3.0-hadoop2
COPY wait-for-cassandra-and-elasticsearch.sh ./
COPY conf/janusgraph-cql-es.properties ./
CMD ["./wait-for-cassandra-and-elasticsearch.sh", "data_storage:9160", "data_index:9200", "./bin/gremlin-server.sh", "./conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server-berkeleyje.yaml"]
```

See full code in Github Repository:
https://github.com/nvizo/janusgraph-cluster-example

Comment: I think my problem may be that I am trying to use nodetool on the JanusGraph container without having the JanusGraph container join the Cassandra cluster first. In other words nodetool only shows the status of the nodes that are in the cluster that it is a part of. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should refer to your cassandra container name as hostname when running nodetool from your janusgraph container. Something along the lines of:

```
docker exec -it ns-orchestration_data_janusgraph_1 bin/nodetool -h data_storage -u cassandra -pw <my-password-here> status
```

Give it a try and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Can you provide the `wait-for-cassandra-and-elasticsearch.sh` script, along with other necessary files, like conf files etc, to build the whole environment? I can try to debug it  by running it here

Comment: Thanks, I created a minimum example in github here: https://github.com/nvizo/janusgraph-cluster-example